# Will antiderivative always be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Suppose f(x) is continuous on [0,1]. Obviously, such a function will be integrable. Will antiderivative be always differentiable on (0,1)? The answer is "Yes" by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

But what if f(x) is not continuous, can it still be integrable but have non-differentiable antiderivative? What confuses me is that I always thought about integrand as the derivative of an antiderivative. So if we find a non-differentiable antiderivative, how can we relate it back to the integrand?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You know antiderivatives are always differentiable (this is so by definition). Thus your assumption `"assuming that we find nondifferentiable antiderivative"` serves no purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "nondifferentiable antiderivative"?

Comment: I think the OP might be talking about something like integrating $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \\ 0 & x =0 \\ \end{cases}$. Note that in *some* sense the *antiderivative* will be $\lvert x \rvert$, but this function is not differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question makes sense now and can be reopened. The answer is of course that the integrand can still be recovered from the antiderivative by using more general notion of differentiation than the classical one, namely so called weak derivatives http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative

Comment: @Conifold But then it can only be recovered almost everywhere (or as an equivalence class of functions), not in the classical sense.